# Stack overflow error when importing WSDL into Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, wsdl, delphi-7

I am trying to import a WSDL into Delphi 7 using the WSDLImporter (as well as the WSDLImp command line).

When using the WSDLImporter, the memory usage of Delphi just starts increasing until it crashes (no error) or I get a Stack overflow error.

When using the command line tool I get the following

```
Borland WSDLIMP Version 2.2 - $Rev: 10138 $
Copyright (c) 2007 Borland Software Corporation
Reading: https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-3/nonpci?wsdl
Import : https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-3/nonpci?wsdl:0
*Error*: http://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-3/nonpci?xsd=xsd0
*Error*: http://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-3/nonpci?xsd=xsd1
*Error*: http://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-3/nonpci?xsd=xsd2
Import : http://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-3/nonpci?wsdl=wsdl0
Import : http://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-3/nonpci?wsdl
Import : http://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-3/nonpci?wsdl=wsdl0
Import : http://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-3/nonpci?wsdl
```

This then loops through the last 2 lines over and over again. Obviously this shows an error but there are no further details on what that error maybe.

I have created a C# project in *Microsoft Visual Studio* and added this as a web reference without any issues but I need to have it in Delphi 7 also due to legacy code.

The address for the WSDL is

https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-3/nonpci?wsdl

I have also tried to load this using soapUI without any errors.

**EDIT**
I have downloaded the trial version of Delphi XE2 (mentioned in another question as a possible solution) and it has given me the following at the top of my PAS file. (I can upload the entire code if necessary)

I'm assuming that there is a problem with the WSDL file that Delphi doesn't like. Any clues on what I can ask the WSDL developer to change so that it will import?

```
// ************************************************************************ //
// The types declared in this file were generated from data read from the
// WSDL File described below:
// WSDL     : https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-3/nonpci?wsdl
//  >Import : http://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-3/nonpci?wsdl=wsdl0
//  >Import : http://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-3/nonpci?wsdl
//  >Import : https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-3/nonpci?wsdl>0
//  >Import : http://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-3/nonpci?wsdl>0
// Encoding : utf-8
// Version  : 1.0
// (9/02/2012 2:32:14 PM - - $Rev: 37707 $)
// ************************************************************************ //

unit nonpci;

interface

uses InvokeRegistry, SOAPHTTPClient, Types, XSBuiltIns;

type

  // ************************************************************************ //
  // The following types, referred to in the WSDL document are not being represented
  // in this file. They are either aliases[@] of other types represented or were referred
  // to but never[!] declared in the document. The types from the latter category
  // typically map to predefined/known XML or Embarcadero types; however, they could also 
  // indicate incorrect WSDL documents that failed to declare or import a schema type.
  // ************************************************************************ //
  // !:CreateScheduleResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:CreateSchedule  - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:ClearScheduleResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:ClearSchedule   - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:ChangeScheduledAmountResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:GetPayments     - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:GetPaymentDetailPlusNextPaymentInfoResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:ChangeScheduledAmount - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:GetPaymentsResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:ChangeScheduledDate - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:IsSystemLockedResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:IsSystemLocked  - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:PaymentExchangeVersionResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:PaymentExchangeVersion - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:IsBsbValidResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:TestFunction    - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:ChangeScheduledDateResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:IsBsbValid      - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:TestFunctionResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:GetCustomerDetails - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:ChangeCustomerStatusResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:AddPayment      - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:GetCustomerDetailsResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:ChangeCustomerStatus - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:AddCustomerResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:AddCustomer     - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:EditCustomerDetailsResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:EditCustomerDetails - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:AddPaymentResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:GetPaymentDetail - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:GetPaymentStatusResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:GetPaymentDetailPlusNextPaymentInfo - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:GetPaymentDetailResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:GetPaymentStatus - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:DeletePaymentResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:DeletePayment   - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:GetScheduledPaymentsResponse - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
  // !:GetScheduledPayments - "https://px.ezidebit.com.au/"[Lit][]
```

Comment: you're talking about Delphi 7, however in the log it says "Copyright (c) 2007", if I remember correctly, delphi 7 would be "Copyright (c) 2002", note 2007 != 2002, is it possible that in your search path is delphi 2006/7 and not delphi 7? try calling "C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\bin\WSDLImp.exe" in CMD to make sure you're calling the correct WSDLImp

Comment: @DorinDuminica, the OP is using this updated importer http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/24535

Comment: ouch, my bad, but maybe he should give a try the original one, it worths a shot...

Comment: @Dorin sorry this screen shot must have been from the updated importer. Tried with the original with same results.

Comment: wow... it been over 20 min. and D7's importer is still working... it uses over 170 MB/RAM but no response yet, and I'm running it on a pretty snappy system... I wonder if the WSDL is not defining aliases in different files which can create a "never ending" loop that resulted in stack overflow...

Comment: Checking http head on your url is causing HTTP/1.1 302 redirect to the same url. that is why the endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering the question but maybe helpful: Free Pascal has a  **Web Service Toolkit** which also has an WSDL importer. The documentation says it works with Delphi too.

> "Web Service Toolkit” is a web services package for FPC, Lazarus and
>   Delphi; “Web Service Toolkit” is meant to ease web services
>   consumption and creation by FPC, Lazarus and Delphi users.

http://wiki.freepascal.org/Web_Service_Toolkit

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Think we are going to have to write an Active X control exposing the web service methods in Visual studio and consume that in Delphi 7.

Comment: Glad I could help! For very simple web services, a HTTP Server / Client link could also be an option. Or a message oriented middleware based on open source solutions (see my profile home page).